# SQL | Aggregation

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

My objective is to get a table such as this:
 **Request:**
*Wards where the annual cost of drugs prescribed exceeds 25*

```
ward_no | year | cost      
     w2 | 2007 | 34  
     w4 | 2007 | 160  
     w5 | 2006 | 26  
     w5 | 2007 | 33
```

> I would input a picture but lack reputation points.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
select      w.ward_no,
            year(pn.start_date)     as year,
            pn.quantity * d.price   as cost
from        ward w,
            patient pt,
            prescription pn,
            drug d
where       w.ward_no = pt.ward_no
        and
            pn.drug_code = d.drug_code
        and 
            pn.patient_id = pt.patient_id
group by    w.ward_no, 
            year,
            cost
having      cost > 25
order by    w.ward_no, year
```

My current output is such:

```
    ward_no|year|cost
    'w2'   |2006|0.28
    'w2'   |2007|3.20
    'w2'   |2007|9.50
    'w2'   |2007|21.60
    'w3'   |2006|10.08
    'w3'   |2007|4.80
    'w4'   |2006|4.41
    'w4'   |2007|101.00
    'w4'   |2007|58.80
    'w5'   |2006|25.20
    'w5'   |2006|0.56
    'w5'   |2007|20.16
    'w5'   |2007|12.60
```

How would I reduce each ward_no to have only a single row of year (say 2006 or 2007) instead of having x of them?
Any help would be very much appreciated I am really stuck and have no clue what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by ward and year, and sum up the costs:

```
select w.ward_no,
       year(pn.start_date) as year,
       sum(pn.quantity * d.price) as cost
  from ward w
  inner join patient pt
    on pt.ward_no = w.ward_no
  inner join prescription pn
    on pn.patient_id = pt.patient_id
  inner join drug d
    on d.drug_code = pn.drug_code
  group by w.ward_no, 
           year(pn.start_date)
  having sum(pn.quantity * d.price) > 25
  order by w.ward_no, year
```

What flavor of SQL is this supposed to be for?

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping by cost, so each cost gets a new line.  Remove the cost from your grouping

```
select      w.ward_no,
        year(pn.start_date)     as year,
        avg(pn.quantity * d.price)   as cost
from        ward w,
        patient pt,
        prescription pn,
        drug d
where       w.ward_no = pt.ward_no
    and
        pn.drug_code = d.drug_code
    and 
        pn.patient_id = pt.patient_id
group by    w.ward_no, 
        year
having       avg(pn.quantity * d.price) > 25
order by    w.ward_no, year
```

Comment: it tells me that I cannot do it that. the cost has to be in the group by clause

Comment: Ah, you'll need to tell it how to handle the 'cost' field when you group by the previous 2. in your current output I see: 'w2' |2007|3.20 'w2' |2007|9.50 'w2' |2007|21.60 . do you want the average of these values? If so, put a avg() around the calculation that gets to cost.  Editted my answer to include the script for you.

Comment: I changed the having cost > 25 to having avg(pn.quantity * d.price) > 25. cost > 25 will work on a couple databases, otherwise the having clause usually needs the calcualtion in it and not just the column alias you gave it.

Comment: I need a sum of these values multiplied by the drugs cost that is taken from the drugs table. However, when I try to do SUM(pn.quantity) * d.price I get invalid use of aggregation error.

Comment: WHat database are you working with?  Oh..and I just had a duh moment.   When you say cost, are you referring to the cost column in the drug table or are you referring to the pn.quantity * d.price calculation?

Comment: I am not sure what type of SQL is it I know that the program is SQL Anywhere by Sybase. It has been given to us students by the university. That probably wont help much. My apologies for ambiguity : by cost I refer to sum(pn.quantity) * d.price. However, when i do that it tells the invalid use of aggregate function

Comment: brackets aren't quite right. sum(pn.quantity) * d.price change to sum(pn.quantity * d.price).  Ha, I'm doing someones homework, aren't I?

Comment: I have tried both ways and it just keeps telling me invalid use of aggregate function. I am really clueless how I can achieve this objective.

Comment: indeed you are. I had to come to stackoverflow due to my inability to understand why my query doesn't execute properly to achieve proposed objective.

Comment: I have just executed his example and it actually worked! Trying to compare it against my own query to see where did I make a mistake. Now I only have to round the numbers in cost! I think you were right it was a problem in my group by clause. I think I need to revert back to documentation about clauses and their functionality. I will UP your comment!